# create-react-app & jest — SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, create-react-app

NOTE: I fixed this by moving all of the code inside my `src/nod_modules` folder into the `src` folder directly and deleting `src/node_modules` as per this short thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4241

---

I am using create-react-app and having trouble running Jest.

When I attempt to import any one of my React components into my test file, I get an error when I `yarn test`:

```
Test suite failed to run

.../src/node_modules/common/ErrorMessage.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(
module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest)
{import React from 'react'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

This is what my test file looks like:

```
// test.test.js

// attempting to import
import ErrorMessage from '../node_modules/common/ErrorMessage.js'

// dummy test
test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(1 + 2).toBe(3)
})
```

However, the error does not get thrown if I'm at the root of the src file, importing my index.js. At that point, the error gets thrown in the first file that index.js imports. For example:

**test.test.js**

```
import index from './index'
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import './style/index.css'
import LoginContainer from './node_modules/user/LoginContainer'
import NewUser from './node_modules/user/NewUser'
// etc.
```

**terminal output**

```
 FAIL  src/test.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/hannahmccain/Desktop/DEV/expense-report/fullstack-expense-report/client/src/node_modules/user/LoginContainer.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React, { Component } from 'react'
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:11:164)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/test.test.js:3:14)
```

It seems like, in the context of Jest, Babel isn't able to compile the files in src/node_modules properly. I'm just at a loss as to how to correct that! Any insights would be appreciated.

FYI, Jest is supposed to work out-of-the-box with create-react-app, and I don't want to eject. Without ejecting, I'm unable to make certain changes I've seen recommended elsewhere, such as updating the Jest settings in my package.json.

Answer (score 9):

To follow up with @Himanshu Singh answer, by adding this in my package.json helped me resolved this error.

```
{
  test: react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!ui-core)/\" --env=jsdom
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, this saved me from going into the depths of ejecting and doing custom configurations, worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

The code inside `node_modules/user/LoginContainer.js` is not a production release (babelified version) as it still has those import statement.

Jest that comes pre-configured with create-react-app, excludes everything inside `node_modules` from babel-transformation before running tests assuming that the code inside `node_modules` would be pre-babelified.

And since your module inside node_modules isn't babelified, jest throws error as soon as it encounters import statement.

**Solution**

**1.** You must be having a build script for your node_module in use. Try placing the production release of your module inside node_modules.This will do the trick but will also create further issues (as per my experience).

**2.** Start configuring jest and its dependencies explicitly without ejecting. Essentially by changing your test script to `jest --env=jsdom`. You will need to install jest, react-dom, babel-transforms-* explicitly and then configure using jest configuration inside package.json.

Here you need to focus on two major configuration option - `transformIgnorePatterns` and `transform`.

In short, transform everything and ingnore everything that is already transformed.

Take a look at Jest [configuration](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html) section for more details.

Comment: thanks for this response! I ended up simply removing the `src/node_modules` folder, as that was causing the issue, so I wasn't able to test out your solution. if it ends up working for someone else i will mark it as the accepted answer!

Comment: I am unsure whether your step will not get you stuck in near future. Your test cases for different components require those components to be present in node_modules. Can you post a link to your repository for me to review and propose you the exact configuration ?